# Error al hacer deploy en vercel

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

Estoy tratando de hacer `deploy` de mi app desarrollada en `reactJS vite`, a `vercel` pero me sale el siguiente error

```
    error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./Components/Wsp/Wsp" from "src/App.jsx"
    at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:2001:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22995:24)
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22958:26
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

No entiendo cual es el error de igual manera agrego lo que tengo en mi `App.jsx`

```
     import "./App.css";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Pages/Home";
import { AboutUs } from "./Pages/AboutUs";
import { Contact } from "./Pages/Contact";
import { Estates } from "./Pages/Estates";
import { Properties } from "./Pages/Properties";
import { Footer } from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import { Wsp } from "./Components/Wsp/Wsp";
import { Services } from "./Pages/Services";
import { PageNotFound } from "./Components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound";
import { Login } from "./Components/Login/Login";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/Nosotros" element={<AboutUs />} />
        <Route path="/Contacto" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/Propiedades" element={<Estates />} />
        <Route path="/Propiedades/:id" element={<Properties />} />
        <Route path="/Servicios" element={<Services />} />
        <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/404" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
      </Routes>
      {location.pathname !== "/404" && location.pathname !== "/login" && (
        <Footer />
      )}
      {location.pathname !== "/404" && location.pathname !== "/login" && (
        <Wsp />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Y este es mi componente `Wsp`

```
import React from "react";
import "./Wsp.css";
import whatIcon from "../../assets/whatsaap.svg";
import insIcon from "../../assets/instagram.svg";

export const Wsp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="social">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://wa.link/9qoe0y"
            target="_blank"
            className="icon-whatsaap"
          >
            <img src={whatIcon} alt="Whatsaap" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="https://www.instagram.com/s.m.real_estate/"
            target="_blank"
            className="icon-instagram"
          >
            <img src={insIcon} alt="Instagram" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Pensé que el problema podría ser por que lo tenia en minúscula y lo actualice pero no se arreglo, alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema, es la primera vez que intento hacer un `deploy` en `vercel`.

EDIT-----
Adjunto imagen de la estructura de mis carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir una imagen de tu directorio de carpetas?

Comment: @Skotpx Listo, ya la añadi

Comment: Puede que en algún componente que renderices en App.jsx estés llamando a "wsp" en minúscula/sin .jsx y esté el error ahí? También puedes comprobar que donde llames a Wsp lo llamas con ".jsx" ?

Comment: No el componente Wsp solo lo llamo en App.jsx e hice las pruebas que me dicen y nada :c

Comment: Agrega todo tu app.jsx por favor

Comment: @Skotpx Ya lo añadí

Comment: Si estás haciendo el deployment desde un repo en Github, ese tipo de errores se dan cuando en el repo tenés el archivo o la carpeta wsp en minúsculas, Github tiene problema para diferenciar mayúsculas de minúsculas, si la subiste en minúscula y luego la cambias a mayúscula local, en el repo sigue quedando en minúscula, por lo que deberías fijarte en el repo directamente en la página de Github si está el archivo o la carpeta en minúsculas, si es así resolviendo eso debería solucionar..

Comment: @LuisS.Romero Tienes razón, mi componente esta en mayúsculas pero mi carpeta esta en minúsculas, puede que por eso falle como puedo hacer para actualizar eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error se presenta al hacer el deploy cuando en el repo en Github está la carpeta o el archivo en minúsculas y localmente en mayúsculas o viceversa.

Esto se genera cuando se sube un proyecto de una forma y posteriormente se cambia localmente a otra.

En ese caso Github no diferencia las mayúsculas de minúsculas al hacer el push al repo, pero al hacer el deploy la ruta intenta acceder a un archivo o carpeta que no existe realmente y devuelve ese error.

**Una forma de resolver esto podría ser:**

1. Respaldar la carpeta o archivo fuera del proyecto local (ej. en escritorio).
2. Borrar la carpeta o archivo en el proyecto local y hacer el push al repo para que se borre también en Github.
3. Volver a poner la carpeta o archivo respaldado/a en el proyecto local.
4. Hacer push al repo nuevamente para que se suba con los cambios generados.
5. Intentar hacer deploy nuevamente (Esto puede tener que repetirse con varios archivos o carpetas si se hicieron cambios de mayúsculas a minúsculas o viceversa posterior a subir el proyecto a Github, en ese caso los logs de Vercel te ayudarán a identificarlos.)

---

En este caso de acuerdo al error, el problema se genera en la línea:

```
import { Wsp } from "./Components/Wsp/Wsp";
```

En Github directamente verifica que las carpetas Componetnts y Wsp están en mayúsculas, así como el arvhico Wsp.jsx.